# Python: Combination with criteria

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I have the following **list of combinations**:

**a = [(1,10),(2,8),(300,28),(413,212)]**

**b = [(8,28), (8,15),(10,21),(28,34),(413,12)]**

I want to create a **new combination list** from these two lists which follow the following criteria:

**A**. **List a and List b have common elements**.

- The second element of the tuple in list a equals the first element of the 
   Tuple in the list b.
- Combination of List a and List b should form a new combination:

  **d = [(1,10,21),(2,8,28),(2,8,15),(300,28,34)]**

  - *All other tuples in both lists which do not satisfy the criteria get ignored.*

**QUESTIONS**

1. Can I do this criteria based combination using itertools?
2. What is the most elegant way to solve this problem with/without using modules?
3. How can one display the output in excel sheet to display each element of a tuple in list d to a separate column such as:

   **d = [(1,10,21),(2,8,28),(2,8,15),(300,28,34)]** is displayed in excel as:

**Col A** = [1, 2, 2, 300]

**Col B** = [10,8,8,28]

**Col C** = [21,28,15,34]

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Have tried itertools but could not find an appropriate criteria option. Running a for loop is not working. So far I am generating a csv file of the output and then copying and pasting it in excel.                                
                                                                                                                
 k = list(itertools.product(b,c))

import csv

with open ('Combination.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    csv_app = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_app.writerow(k)'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` works like a charm for `excel`.

Here is the code:

```
a = [(1,10),(2,8),(300,28),(413,212)]

b = [(8,28), (8,15),(10,21),(28,34),(413,12)]

c = [(x, y, t) for x, y in a for z, t in b if y == z]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(c)
df.to_excel('MyFile.xlsx', header=False, index=False)
```